# Ruby Date Time Subtraction

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, duration

I am trying to calculate the exact duration a process took from some log file result. After parsing the log, I reached at the following stage:

```
my_array = ["Some_xyz_process", "Start", "2018-07-12", "12:59:53,397", "End", "2018-07-12", "12:59:55,913"]
```

How can I subtract the start date and time from the end date and time in order to retrieve the exact duration the process took?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_array = ["Some_xyz_process",
            "Start", "2018-07-12", "12:59:53,397",
            "End", "2018-07-12", "12:59:55,913"]

require 'date'

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S,%L'
is = my_array.index('Start')
  #=> 1
ie = my_array.index('End') 
  #=> 4
DateTime.strptime(my_array[ie+1] + my_array[ie+2], fmt).to_time -
DateTime.strptime(my_array[is+1] + my_array[is+2], fmt).to_time
  #=> 2.516 (seconds)
```

See [DateTime#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and [DateTime#](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) (the latter for format directives). As long as the date and time formats are known I always prefer `strptime` to `parse`. Here's an example of why:

```
DateTime.parse 'Theresa May has had a bad week over Brexit'
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458240j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.
```

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby solution. There may be Rails methods that would make the job easier, but not knowing Rails I can't speak to that.

Comment: Wow. This example. I never knew `DateTime#parse` could go this crazy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the date and time field and use `Time.parse` to convert it to a time object and then calculate the difference in number of seconds

```
Time.parse('2018-07-12 12:59:55,397').to_i - Time.parse('2018-07-12 12:59:53,913').to_i
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Subtracting start time from end time would give positive result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I agree that concat and then substract is also good idea. Thanks